# Distance between molecules in outer space

Tags: pressure, astrophysics, estimation, density, space

I read that space has a pressure of about $1.322*10^{-11}$. I am curious to know how far apart molecules are from each other because of this extremely low pressure.

Comment: [One atom per cubic centimeter, on average](https://www.google.com/search?q=density+of+outer+space).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what exactly you mean by 'space'. In our solar system (interplanetary medium) the particle density is about $10-100/cm^3$ so the atoms/molecules would be a few millimeters apart. In interstellar space it is similar but the density can be less or more depending on where you are (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_medium#Interstellar_matter ). In intergalactic space the density is even much less, about 1 particle per $m^3$, so there the particles are about 1 m apart.

It is not clear to which scenario your pressure figure is relating, because a) you don't give any units, and b) pressure depends on temperature as well.